# Using Android permissions in MonoGame

Tags: c#, android, monogame

how do you ask for android permission (e.g. file, notification, camera) using monogame or a library that works with net6.0-android?

I've tried finding it online but I can't find anything.

Comment: This is in the manfest file, but ask do you need the permission? if so, on install or can you ask per use?

Comment: it depends I need notification on install and file when the user wants to export the save file